# MASM function error

Tags: c#, assembly, x86, masm

I've just finished my C# part of code and now it's time for assembler. This is a method i wanna rewrite using MASM:

```
private long powerModulo(long a, long b, long m)             
    {

        long i, result = 1, x = a % m;

        for (i = 1; i <= b; i <<= 1)
        {
            x %= m;
            if ((b & i) != 0)
            {
                result *= x;
                result %= m;
            }
            x *= x;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I'm kinda new to this(i mean assembler) and i have a problem at the beggining. 
I started by creating variables and calculate x variable. Here is my code:

```
Modulo PROC stdcall a:dword, b:dword, m:dword

 i DD 0
 result DD 1
 x DD 0

 MOV EAX, a
 MOV ECX, m
 CDQ 
 IDIV ECX
 MOV x, EDX
 MOV EAX, x
 ret 

Modulo  ENDP
```

and i got an error of AccessViolationEcxeption. Anyone has an idea what's wrong?

Here is where i call asm function:

```
namespace GUI
{
  unsafe class FunkcjeAsemblera
  {
    [DllImport("bibliotekaASM.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern long Modulo(long a, long b, long m); 


    public long callModulo(long a, long b, long m)
    {
        return Modulo(a, b, m);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should not define your variables in the code section. Rather use data, or even better, use local variables. When you need them. In this case `i` and `result` are unused, and you don't even need `x`.

Comment: I know i'm not using them yet. I just want to rewrite it step by step. I stuck at calculating x variable.

Comment: You declared them in the code flow for your function. That means the cpu will try to execute them as instructions. Needless to say, that is bad.

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to declare local variables explicitly with `LOCAL` (NB: they will be not initialized),

2) You're handling with `LONG` which are a 64-bit value. The arguments are pushed as `QWORD` onto the stack. The return-value is passed through EDX:EAX.

I corrected your example accordingly:

```
Modulo PROC STDCALL a:QWORD, b:QWORD, m:QWORD
LOCAL i:DWORD, result:DWORD, x:DWORD

    MOV EAX, DWORD PTR a
    MOV EDX, DWORD PTR a + 4
    MOV ECX, DWORD PTR m
    IDIV ECX
    MOV x, EDX
    MOV EAX, x
    CDQ             ; EAX = EDX:EAX (signed)
    RET

Modulo  ENDP
```

Comment: MOV EAX, DWORD PTR a MOV EDX, DWORD PTR a + 4 i don't get this lines, can u explain to me, how it works?

Comment: @kobasek: `EAX` gets the "low" DWORD of the QWORD `a`, `EDX` gets the "high" DWORD of `a`. After that, the QWORD `a` is in the registers `EDX:EAX`. `IDIV ECX` means: "EDX:EAX / ECX = EAX remainder EDX".

Comment: Thank you for answer. So what about m variable? It's also a long type.

Comment: @kobasek: Yeah! You found it! A long/long-division is complicated in 32-bit-assembler. So I simply presumed that m < 0x100000000 and the high DWORD of m is 0x00000000 - and "forgot" it. If m exceeds 0xFFFFFFFF the result will be wrong.

Comment: Any suggestions how can I manage with that in the most simpliest way?

Comment: @kobasek: Suggestion for beginners: Don't work with `long` and even don't work with `int`. Handling negative numbers can be very annoying. Use `uint` (unsigned DWORD) instead.

Comment: It is possible to move floating-point number from coprocessor to registers? I know that i have to use variable so I declare `var dd ?` and then i try `fst [var]` but it results: _An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in GUI.exe_